# Plotting with streamlit slider bar is really slow

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I am trying to create a plot in Streamlit that responds to a slider bar, but it is extremely slow.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import streamlit as st


if st.session_state.get('fig') is None:
    st.session_state['freq'] = np.arange(0.0, 5.1, 0.1).round(2)    
    f = st.session_state['freq'][2]
    st.session_state['fig'] = go.Figure()
    st.session_state['fig'].add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            name=str(f),
            x=np.arange(0, 10.01, 0.01),
            y=np.sin(f* np.arange(0, 10.01, 0.01))))
    
def sldier_callback():
    f = st.session_state['slider_freq']
    x = st.session_state['fig'].data[0].x
    st.session_state['fig'].data[0].y = np.sin(f*x)
    st.session_state['fig'].data[0].name = str(f)


f = st.select_slider(
    label='Frequency', 
    options=st.session_state['freq'],
    value=2,
    on_change=sldier_callback,
    key='slider_freq'
)

st.plotly_chart(st.session_state['fig'])
```

[image]

The [Plotly chart](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/), on the other hand, is much more responsive to the slider bar. It creates and hides the figures at the beginning and then unhides the correct figure when you move the slider bar.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


fig = go.Figure()
for step in np.arange(0, 5, 0.1):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            name="f = " + str(step),
            x=np.arange(0, 10, 0.01),
            y=np.sin(step * np.arange(0, 10, 0.01))))

fig.data[10].visible = True

# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[              
            {"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
            {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],  
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

I tried to do the same in Streamlit with the following code, but it is still very slow. Does anyone know how to speed it up? Thanks!

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


if st.session_state.get('fig') is None:
    st.session_state['freq'] = np.arange(0.0, 5.01, 0.1).round(2)
    st.session_state['fig'] = go.Figure()
    for f in st.session_state['freq']:
        st.session_state['fig'].add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                visible=False,
                name=str(f),
                x=np.arange(0, 10.01, 0.01),
                y=np.sin(f*np.arange(0, 10.01, 0.01))))
    
    st.session_state['selected'] = 0
    st.session_state['fig'].data[0].visible = True


def sldier_callback():
    i = st.session_state['selected']
    st.session_state['fig'].data[i].visible = False
    freq = st.session_state['slider_freq']
    i = np.where(st.session_state['freq']==freq)[0][0]
    st.session_state['fig'].data[i].visible = True
    st.session_state['selected'] = i


f = st.select_slider(
    label='freq', 
    options=st.session_state['freq'],
    value=2,
    on_change=sldier_callback,
    key='slider_freq'
)

st.plotly_chart(st.session_state['fig'])
```

Comment: I ran all your codes samples. Indeed the plotly is instantaneously updated (no need to release the mouse button). However I find both streamlit codes quite fast: as soon as the cursor is released and the value checked, it takes a few ms to update. Probably <200ms. Isn't it what you observe? You need it to be as fast as plotly , i.e. update without release mouse button ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make it as fast as plotly. But I am not sure if that is possible with streamlit.